# Flexibility inside TextView like contains strings changeable

Tags: android, android-studio, textview

What I want to make is I have a TextView contains a message
the message are able to editing by the users to send the message
to the manager
the problem is the message it should contain sentence that can't change
also there a part able to change so I want to put some words stable with stable color with some entring message from users

Tried to make this layout to explain a little bit of my idea

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZ44n.png)

also prefer kotlin code